# Modifying two different attributes of two children of a certain div

Tags: html, css

I have part of an HTML definition which looks like this.

```
<div id="photoindex" class="content">
    <div class="photocategory">
      <a href="/photo/clouds"><img src="img.jpg"></a>
      <h1><a href="/photo/clouds">Clouds</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `h1` should be invisible until the image is hovered over, at which point the `h1` becomes visible, and the `img` opacity is reduced. My current attempt has a slight flaw which cannot be ignored.

```
div#photoindex h1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

div#photoindex h1:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#photoindex img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

div#photoindex a:hover + h1 {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#photoindex h1:hover + a {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

With this, I can mouse over the image and have the `h1` appear, and the image opacity go down. However, if I move the mouse over the `h1`, the image opacity returns to normal. I've tried using the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors, but that doesn't appear to work. I've had no luck trying to apply things to `.photocategory` either.

```
div.photocategory:hover a {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

div.photocategory:hover h1 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This changes the opacity, but has no apparent effect on the visibility of the `h1`. Can I do what I want without Javascript? Perhaps a different HTML structure would work better?

Comment: The opacity is supposed to be applied only to the image, not the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what might possibly be a better way of doing things. If `div.photocategory:hover` is used, then hovering over that element produces the effect, even if the cursor is not over the image at the time. This is not a problem for places where the image takes up the whole `photocategory`, but for those where it does not, the problem arises.

The main problem was caused by a mouseover on the `h1` causing that element to be activated, where we actually want to ignore it. To solve this issue, you can use the `pointer-events` property as below.

```
div#photoindex div.photocategory h1 {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: -40px 0 0 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div#photoindex div.photocategory a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

div#photoindex div.photocategory a:hover + h1 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This CSS more accurately represents the problem, and the result can be seen at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucnBv/8/). Setting `pointer-events: none;` drops pointer events through to the element below the `h1`, in this case the `img` element, and we do not need more CSS to modify the `h1` opacity.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVPYF/) illustrates the issue with using `photocategory:hover`. Mousing over the blank space to the right of the image causes the hover event to be activated.

Answer (score 1):

I think applying the styles to `.photocategory` will work, assuming your parent divs aren't collapsing.

```
div#photoindex div.photocategory:hover a {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

div#photoindex div.photocategory:hover h1 a {
    opacity: 1;
}

div#photoindex div.photocategory:hover h1 {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#photoindex div.photocategory h1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWkhd/6/)

Comment: This results in the opacity of both elements being set to 0.7, as the `h1` has an `a` inside it.